# How to find maximum value in a table n oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with three columns and all having numeric values. How to find what is the maximum value in it. Suppose the following table has maximum value 28, so how to find it.

```
|col1 |  col2  | col3
  12      14     16
  21      28     27
  25      24     26
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your title and question are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Use a union with `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(val) AS max_val
FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS val FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT col3 FROM yourTable
) t;
```

Comment: I need one value suppose 31 is the greatest value. Your answer gives a column of values. I tried Select max(Greatest(col1,col2,col3)  as greatest_value from myTable.

Comment: Your requirement was unclear, at least to me.  Check the updated answer.

Comment: I have to find one value which is maximum in whole table, i.e. highest numerical value present in whole table. The above solution works.

Comment: This solution can use indexes on the columns, so it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
select max(greatest(col1, col2,col3)) as greatest from t1;

select greatest(max(col1), max(col2),max(col3)) from t1;
```